# Is the Focusrite Scratlett 2i2 and Rode NT1 Kit mic a good starting set for podcasting?

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces

I am thinking about buying a mic and an audio interface for podcasting on my MacBook Pro. I am new to this stuff, and based on my research, I came to the conclusion that, I need a large diaphragm, condenser mic (correct me if I am wrong).

After a lot of Googling, I want to buy a [Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 USB 2.0](http://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i2) audio interface and a [Rode NT1 Kit mic](http://www.rode.com/nt1).

I wonder if these two are good choices for podcasting, and if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Dave is right, in a way, about the economics of the USB mic, but people still like nice quality in their podcasts as they listen, anything you can do to enhance quality will be appreciated including investing in the Rode and the interface.  And that focusrite could come in handy if you want to record a two person interview at some point with another mic for example.  I like your choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off the Rode NT1A is one of my FAVORITE mics in that price range so I would never tell anyone not to buy it. Its versatile and great sounding.

But...

For podcasting you only really need to record your voice and the small tone differences you get from one mic vs another will be less of a concern. I might suggest something like [this mic](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Audio-Technica-AT2020USB-USB-Condenser-Microphone-104992326-i1391208.gc) which will give you a mic and interface all in one. You can then use your headphone output for monitoring and save a few dollars in the process. While interfaces are great you may be paying for channels you don't really need (unless you also want to record music or something)

**A note on protecting your NT1A**

This applies to all large (and small) diaphragm condenser mics but you should note that elements are very delicate and can be ruined by spit and other moisture. Save your self the potential headache and get a [pop filter](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Musician-s-Gear-Pop-Filter-107218828-i1423935.gc) if you get a condenser. This will keep your mic safe, protect the element and reduce your "P" sounds. You wont need something like this for the SM-58 mentioned below in my edit as its built in to the head but it never hurts to put something like [this](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Shure-A58WS-GRA-SM58-Windscreen-for-Ball-Type-Microphones-100063208-i1169212.gc) over the element.

**Edit:**

I would like to mention that your setup is a very solid and a great starting point for any type of recording. It will deliver great quality right out of the box. I mentioned the USB mics as they tend to deliver very solid quality for the price and keep the whole situation way simpler although the note on a 2 person interview is a very good point that I had not thought of. If budget is not a serious concern than I would take the setup you mention over a USB mic. If you are looking for other suggestions I love MOTU products and they make a smaller interface you can find [here](http://www.guitarcenter.com/MOTU-Microbook-II-Audio-Interface-107756132-i2468406.gc). As I mentioned the NT1A is a great mic but I would not over look the classic [SM-58](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Shure-SM58-Mic-100038284-i1126419.gc) which is often considered a bit of a gold standard in its class of mic. Some very famous recordings have been done with it with great results considers its very modest price. I also really like MXL Mic's I have the V69 but you may be interested in something like [this](http://www.guitarcenter.com/MXL-990-Condenser-Microphone-with-Shockmount-106203706-i1126975.gc) or [this](http://www.guitarcenter.com/MXL-CR-77-Dynamic-Microphone-109984351-i3546378.gc)

Comment: NT1 Kit comes with a pop  filter.

Comment: My apologies it seems it does. When I had bought mine I did not buy the kit and thus remembered it not coming with a pop filter.

Comment: I bought NT1 and Focusrite, and so far, they are great! Very clear sound.